# Export Muliple Layer Selection to Single CSV File in ArcGIS WebApp

Tags: export, csv, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I'm trying to set up a web app that has multiple layers that all have the same fields (each layer is a separate year of data but same data type).

I need to be able to select data points from multiple layers and export the selected features to a single csv file where the records are appended to a single set - not joined since the fields all match up.

Right now, the only widgets I've found allow me to select multiple layers in one go but only export each layer separately. Before I set out trying to build my own custom widget since this seems like a pretty "run-of-the-mill" function for a mapping application, I'm wondering if anyone here knows of a standard or custom widget already out there that achieves this.

I'm working on my app through ArcGIS Web App Builder developer edition.

Comment: How do you want the schema of the final CSV output to be if you arent working with common fields across all layers?

Comment: @KHibma The fields are common across all layers

Comment: But if you mean how would the widget handle it if they weren't --  I'm picturing just adding field names of all layers and fields that are n/a (based on the layer of origin) would be left null on those line items.

Comment: I did a quick search, but I couldn't find any samples or ready made widgets that do this. You might have to roll your own here. Keep in mind, your comment about this being a pretty "run-of-the-mill".... the desktop software doesn't have a 1 button export multiple layers into a single output file. This is a stepped workflow, generally because of concerns with differing schemas and having to rectify this.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it just seems run of the mill because we're considering moving from a service where this feature was available so I guess I just took it for granted and was surprised to not see it in arc.